# Cartesian coordinates of a rotating circle

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotation

I couldn't understand something in the solution of the problem mentioned in this link

[Pendulum with a rotating point of support from Landau-Lifschitz](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100807/pendulum-with-a-rotating-point-of-support-from-landau-lifschitz)

Why do we use the frequency  in the following equation

=cos+sin

How can frequency replace the angle?

Comment: with $~\dot \varphi=\frac{d}{dt}\varphi=\omega~$ and for constant $~ \omega~$ you obtain the angle $~\varphi=\omega\,t=2\pi\,f\,t~$ where f is the frequency

Comment: @Eli is cos(2 ) equal to the cos(ft)?

Comment: No $\omega=2\pi\,f$ so your f is omega